# Как улучшить читабельность?

Tags: html

Здравствуйте!

С трудом разбираюсь с html в связки с c# (.net программирование)!

Как улучшить запись при выводе?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Data User</title>
<style>
.link{display:block; width:300px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; ext-decoration: none; outline:none;}
.link{text-decoration: none; color:#85AB70}
.link:hover{text-decoration: underline; color:green}
.link:active{color:blue}
</style>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href=http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/2/634/w50h50139292026819.png
</head>
<body style="width:100%; height:100%; margin: 0; background: url(http://www.wallpapers4u.org/wp-content/uploads/dark_background_line_surface_65896_1920x1080.jpg) #191919">
<center><h1 style="color:#85AB70; margin:50px 0">Панель парсера</h1><center><a href="#"></a><table style="width: 1000px; margin:50px auto"><tr>
<td style="width: 33.3%; height: 35px; color:#B6EEF7; border:2px solid #707070"><center>NN</center></td>
<td style="width: 33.3%; height: 35px; color:#B6EEF7; border:2px solid #707070"><center>Link</center></td>
<td style="width: 33.3%; height: 35px; color:#B6EEF7; border:2px solid #707070"><center>Login</center></td>
<td style="width: 33.3%; height: 35px; color:#B6EEF7; border:2px solid #707070"><center>Password</center></td></tr>
<center><p style="color:#B6EEF7; margin:50px">Добро пожаловать в панель<center></a><table style="width:10px; margin:50px auto"></center></p></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Знатоки html, не судите ( это связка с c# ) - то есть при компиляции код получается только таким)

**В основном проблема:** большие отступы между 1 и 2-ой строчки!

Comment: `вязка с c#` - это как интересно...

Comment: c# не умеет выводить слово `class`?

Comment: Таки без вашего кода на c# вам тут никто не поможет. Вы неправильно рендерите таблицу.

Comment: @vp_arth, Ну на `c#` оно перестроится, как бы тут в `html таблице` подправить) в этом сложность заключается)

Comment: У вас нигде не открывается вторая строка, в ней нет ячеек, однако она закрывается.. Тег `link` не закрыт. Портянки из стилей нужно убрать в классы.

Comment: Может тут есть умельцы которые вникают в этот апофеоз ) я не сильно понимаю его - в процессе изучения, но может кто-нибудь подправит исход..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1gmznm1m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно уменьшить соответствующие `margin`

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(http://www.wallpapers4u.org/wp-content/uploads/dark_background_line_surface_65896_1920x1080.jpg) #191919;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #85AB70
}

.link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: green
}

.link:active {
  color: blue
}

.panel-table {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.panel-table th,
.panel-table td {
  color: #85AB70;
  width: 31%;
  height: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #707070;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-table th {
  color: #B6EEF7;
}

.panel-table th:nth-child(1),
.panel-table td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 7%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Data User</title>
  <style>

  </style>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href=http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/2/634/w50h50139292026819.png>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="color:#85AB70; margin:50px 0 5px; text-align: center;">Панель парсера</h1>
  <div style="color:#B6EEF7; margin:5px; text-align: center;">Добро пожаловать в панель</div>
  <table class="panel-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NN</th>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Login</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>NN</td>
        <td>Link</td>
        <td>Login</td>
        <td>Password</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @ArteS, четыре колонки по 33.3% шириной каждая - это действительно то, что вы хотите?

Comment: Стили обрамляете тегами `<style></style>`